# Best way to Localize .NET Web Application (Both Server-Side and Client-Side)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, language-agnostic, localization

In the past few days i have be implementing Localization for my web-application written in MVC.
There are 3 main task that brake-down the Lozalization *"Problem"* that I could point out:

1. **Storage:** Store Key-Value pair of strings in multiple languages to be used in your application
2. **Server-Side Access:** Access the Value according to a given Key in your Server Side Script (e.g. Views, Controllers, Web-forms etc...)
3. **Client-Side Access:** Access the Value according to a given Key in your client Side Script (e.g. Java-script)
4. create a culture switching mechanism.

There are several methods to accomplish each task that I have explored and I'm struggling with choosing between them.
There are two questions that I'm interested in:

1. I would like to know what would be the best practice for localization? from your point of view.
   Please write Advantages\ Disadvantages for one method vs. the other.
2. Are there other methods or enhancements that you could suggest.

---

### 1. Storage

#### Resource Files:

- Store Key-Value pairs of localized strings in a resource file
- Create a resource file with the same keys for each culture, e.g. myString.resx, myStrings.he-IL.resex etc...

#### XML Files:

- Create a structured XML file that will contain a parent node for each key and childe nodes for each culture specific value e.g.

  ```
  <string key="myAppName">
      <heIL>some Hebrew value</heIL>
      <enUS>some English value</enUS>
  </string>
  ```

### 2. Server Side Access

- With both *Storage* options it would be fairly easy to get access to from the server side.

  - **Using resource** files a bit easier in that case becuse there are classess that are auto-generated to facilitate access to the values. So you use resources as regular clasess with static properties to access each string value according to a key.
  - **With XML files** you will have to write down the Access Layer code yourself, which is not necessarily a bad thing - because you get much more control that way (only if you need it)

### 3. Client Side Access

Here is where it gets interesting and sometimes complicated.
There where two options that i have explored here and I'm not sure how to proceed.

#### Server-Side Generated Script:

- In your View\ Web-Form add a server script render block inside a `<script>` tag
- From this point dynamically create an Array of keys, or static variables in java script and place the required string inside them.
  Here is an example using Razor engine.

  ```
     <script type="text/javascript">
              k_CultureInfo = "@CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name";
              K_ApplicationName = "@MyStrings.SomeStringKey";
              ....
     </script>
  ```

#### Custom HTTP Handler:

I found the idea in a blog pos here: [Localize text in JavaScript files in ASP.NET](http://madskristensen.net/post/Localize-text-in-JavaScript-files-in-ASPNET.aspx#comment) Here

- Bestially your write an HTTP handler that handles any ".js.axd" request comes to the server.
- The *"ScriptTranslatorHandler"* will read the javascrip file and wil replace any instance of a predefined token e.g. Translate(SomeStringKey) in your java script to the correct string taken by any of the methods described above.

Comment: I don't personally think that trying to lump all types of application into a single resource management mechanism is going to fly unless you spend a very long time on it.  Using the ResourceManager mechanism for server-side generally works very well and you can plugin your own resource providers if, for example, you want drive your resource strings from a database and not resx files.  Client applications should use their own localisation mechanisms for static data - e.g. on Android you use 'Droids resourcing - and then I'd use language header to localise dynamic info coming from the server.

Comment: Just to see if understood correctly, you suggesting to implement your own access layer so you will have more control over where you pull information from regardless of storage method ?

Comment: Personally I prefer the use of resource files. The main reason is the trasparency of project and very easy culture switching.Bind the content of an xml file (which contains language strings like en-US- english) to a dropdownlist. You just have to set culture according to the selection.

Comment: @user829081 True, it seems easier to work with resources because they are a part of the built in localization mechanism already. what would you prefer to do for client side access ?

Comment: Maybe you should check this blog to:[A Localization Handler to serve ASP.NET Resources to JavaScript](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Apr/02/A-Localization-Handler-to-serve-ASPNET-Resources-to-JavaScript) It uses resx file with http handler.

Comment: @user829081 Thanks it strengthens the though that using an HTTP Handler is a better approach but I am still looking for specific advantages over just placing the string in an dynamically generated <script> tag

Comment: Another client-side access method i found [Making your ASP.NET Global Resource files work in JavaScript. IntelliSense included!](http://martinnormark.com/making-your-asp-net-global-resource-files-work-in-javascript-intellisense-included)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resource files:**

Use the resx format. Translation tools will not be able to process the format you proposed since it contains multiple languages in the same file. A typical translation tool would take a source file and generate a matching file for each language after translation. I would avoid the format that you suggested at all costs.

If you want to use an XML, use a single file per language. Also, whatever format you choose, make sure you include context comments for each segment to help translators.

**Server Side Access**

Use the resx and save yourself the time to define the layer

**Client Side Access**

Server side generated script is simpler and more consistent with the sever side access in my opinion.

**Culture switching mechanism**

I assume you are asking about the logic and not the UI. The most common method is to get the user's browser language setting. If the language is set to a language that does not exist in your application, fall back to your default language. You also want to set a cookie with the users selection (in case they change the language manually) so that they are presented with their language of choice next time.

Answer (score -2):

maybe this will help, if its a webapp 
https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/i18n

give it a try!!!

Comment: Well it talks about localization but it does not answer the question, may be you should tray placing it as a commend. the post from Google deals with general directives of localization while the question asks for specific implementation method.